# How to combine radar charts in matplotlib with categories similiar to pie charts

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I'm trying to combine a radar chart in matplotlib with a pie chart so that a I'll have some like this example here:

https://agilityhealthradar.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/TeamHealth_Web_Detailed_View_934-e1531225843825.png

As you can see there is inside of the chart a radar chart where you can put some values and at the outside you have different categories with sub categories. I tried to combine the matplotlib radar chart with a pie chart where I put the categories. But this fails. Does anyone has a good idea how to add in a radar chart some categories with sub categories for the different segments of the radar chart?

Thanks.

----------------------- Edit ---------------------

As suggested I tried to combine a radar chart with a pie chart but I couldn't figure out why it doesn't looks like as expected.

[plot example result with radar chart and a pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8EIS.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8, 8), subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))
sizes = [32, 20, 15, 10, 10, 8, 5]
labels = 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'durian', 'elderberries', 'figs', 'grapes'
d = ax.pie(sizes, labels=labels, radius=1, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90, labeldistance=1.05)
ax.set(aspect="equal")
plt.show()
```

Comment: The radar chart is a polar plot. So first create a polar plot. Then you have two options: You can define the colored patches at the edge of the polar plot. Or you create a new pie chart at the position of the polar plot.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but it doesn't work by combining a radar with a pie chart, see my edited post for further details.

Comment: Well, ok, maybe I wasn't clear enough. Of course the pie should **not** be defined *inside* the polar plot, but rather as a new axes. I added a code to show what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a pie chart at the position of the polar chart. This could look as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8, 8), subplot_kw=dict(polar=True, zorder=1))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.3, right=0.7, top=0.7, bottom=0.3)

sizes = [32, 20, 15, 10, 10, 8, 5]
labels = 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'durian', 'elderberries', 'figs', 'grapes'

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, label="pie axes", zorder=0)
d = ax2.pie(sizes, labels=labels, radius=1.75, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90, labeldistance=1.05)
ax2.set(aspect="equal")
plt.show()
```

[image]